# I am seeing "Selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument" error when trying to open New Tab using selenium 4

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I am using Selenium 4.0.0-alpha-3, webdrivermanager 3.7.1 , Chrome Browser 79 , 
Chrome driver 4.0.0-alpha-3 , JAVA

**code look like:**

```
WebDriverManager.chromedriver().setup();
driver = new ChromeDriver(options);
driver.get("www.Url1.com");     
driver.switchTo().newWindow(WindowType.TAB);
// below code line is throwing error
driver.get("www.Url2.com");
```

**downloaded Maven dependencies, this is what I downloaded** -

```xml
<dependency>
    <groupId>io.github.bonigarcia</groupId>
    <artifactId>webdrivermanager</artifactId>
    <version>3.7.1</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
    <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
    <version>2.6</version>
</dependency>
```

**Error Trace:**

> org.openqa.selenium.InvalidArgumentException: invalid argument
>     (Session info: chrome=79.0.3945.79)
>   Build info: version: '4.0.0-alpha-3', revision: '8c567de6dc'
>   System info: host: 'IL-mike', ip: '10.16.240.29', os.name: 'Windows 10', os.arch: 'amd64', os.version: '10.0', java.version: '12.0.1'
>   Driver info: org.openqa.selenium.chrome.ChromeDriver
>   Capabilities {acceptInsecureCerts: false, browserName: chrome, browserVersion: 79.0.3945.79, chrome: {chromedriverVersion: 79.0.3945.36 (3582db32b3389..., userDataDir: C:\Users\mike\AppData\Loc...}, goog:chromeOptions: {debuggerAddress: localhost:56216}, javascriptEnabled: true, networkConnectionEnabled: false, pageLoadStrategy: normal, platform: WINDOWS, platformName: WINDOWS, proxy: Proxy(), setWindowRect: true, strictFileInteractability: false, timeouts: {implicit: 0, pageLoad: 300000, script: 30000}, unhandledPromptBehavior: dismiss and notify}
>   Session ID: e65fde07f0a168c2399049ab2ffe5866
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstanceWithCaller(Constructor.java:500)
>       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:481)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.createException(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:191)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:125)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.codec.w3c.W3CHttpResponseCodec.decode(W3CHttpResponseCodec.java:52)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.HttpCommandExecutor.execute(HttpCommandExecutor.java:161)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.service.DriverCommandExecutor.execute(DriverCommandExecutor.java:83)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:576)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.get(RemoteWebDriver.java:276)
>       at 
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
>       at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:567)

Comment: thanks for your reply. I made a mistake here for URL. I was giving "www.google.com" and I was seeing issue. During troubleshoot I changed this URL to "h tt ps://www.google.com/" and worked for me perfectly. I thought since it's Alpha version so acting weird. thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of running another `driver.get()` try running it with `driver.execute_script("replace.window.location{"www.Url2.com"}")`

Comment: thanks for your reply. I made a mistake here for URL. I was giving "www.google.com" and I was seeing issue. During troubleshoot I changed this URL to "ht t ps://www.google.com/" and worked for me perfectly. I thought since it's Alpha version so acting weird. thanks